# ¿Por qué no se puede editar un comentario pasada una x cantidad de minutos?

Tags: soporte, comentarios

¿Por qué pasado una x cantidad de minutos (no sé exactamente cuántos), no puedo editar mas mi propio comentario?

Pienso que se debería poder editar en cualquier momento, ya que el usuario puede darse cuenta al cabo de los días (por poner un ejemplo) de que lo que comentó tiene algún error o está mal y debe tener la posibilidad de rectificarlo sin tener que insertar uno nuevo desmintiendo el anterior.

¿O es que hay que tener una cierta reputación para poder hacer esto?

Comment: Creo que es porque un comentario es como una conversacion. Es probable que los comentarios posteriories tengan relación con el comentario superior. Si permites editarlos sin límite podría haber problemas

Comment: Hola Adriana. Esta es la página oficial sobre [cómo funcionan los comentarios](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19756/182862). A pesar que allí se explica que hay una ventana de 5 minutos para editar los comentarios, no se profundiza el por qué no se puede. Levantaré una pregunta en ese meta solicitando dicha explicación o en todo caso que aclaren eso en esa respuesta.

Comment: Qué va. Aquí encontré una pregunta similar a la tuya en ese meta: [Why is the time limit for editing comments only 5 minutes?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/78573/182862). Espero que un alma caritativa pueda colocar una respuesta incluyendo algunas respuestas de allí (varias son buenas), sino yo lo haré en un par de días.

Comment: Sí, tiene sentido lo que dices @MiquelColl. No se si esa sea la mejor respuesta a esto pero a mi me haz convencido. Si lo pones como respuesta te lo marcaré como acertada.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A partir de la información proporcionada por [Luiggi](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/227/luiggi-mendoza) de la pregunta [Why is the time limit for editing comments only 5 minutes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/78573):

Primera [respuesta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/78581):

> El verdadero problema es que, como buenos ciudadanos de segunda clase que son,
>   los comentarios no tienen *historia*.
>
> SE te permite editar casi todo lo demás en cualquier momento porque
>   hay control de edición: En cualquier momento dado,
>   sabemos **quién** cambió **qué**, **cuándo** y **por qué**. Este no es el caso con los
>   comentarios - esta es la razón por los comentarios ya no pueden ser
>   editados después de que el período de gracia termine.

Mi opinión personal (y que también se menciona en [esta respuesta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/78575)):

Los comentarios son como una conversación corta entre usuarios (si fuera larga, tendríamos que ir al [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol)) en la que es muy probable que los comentarios estén relacionados entre sí.

Eso significa que si se pudieran editar los comentarios sin límite el contexto perdería sentido por lo que es muy probable que comentarios posteriores también dejaran de tener sentido.

Es más, como los comentarios se pueden **borrar** en cualquier momento más de una vez he visto en muchas preguntas comentarios que parecen no tener sentido al haberse borrado un comentario anterior. Si además se pudieran editar en cualquier momento el caos sería aún más alto.

Comment: Ya entendí, gracias.

Answer (score -2):

El editar preguntas es un privilegio que se otorga cuando cualquier miembro llega a 1,000 puntos de reputación durante el tiempo Beta del sitio (cosa en la que estamos a fecha). Después del Beta, se requerirán 2,000 puntos.

Si quieres cambiar algo de lo que escribiste, avisa an un moderador al reportar la pregunta.  No se te olvide añadir la nueva edición y nosotros haremos los cambios.

Comment: Creo que @AdrianaHernández no se refiere a la edición de preguntas, sino a la de comentarios :)

Comment: @MiquelColl Tienes toda la razón, entendí mal.

Comment: Además, la información es errónea. Un usuario puede cambiar su propia publicación en cualquier momento (sin importar su reputación, siempre que no tenga un ban), y puede *sugerir una edición*, es decir que puede editarla libremente y la edición será evaluada por revisores en la [cola de ediciones sugeridas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) para ver si se acepta antes de entrar en vigencia... Por otro lado, *nunca* debería reportarse a un moderador pidiendo una edición. Y si se reporta, será rechazado.